# Ruby Haml Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have written a wrapper function in my `config.rb` to prefix and postfix urls for our server.

```
def my_link(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
  if DEV
    link_to(name,options,html_options,&block)
  else
    options[:href] = PREFIX + options[:href] + POSTFIX
    link_to(name,options,html_options,&block)
  end
end
```

and I've found a few instances which don't work as I'd expect.

In my haml files I reference the function and it breaks saying

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end
```

The part I don't understand is that it works fine with the `%a{:href=>""}` syntax.

my haml is as follows:

this part worked:

```
%nav
  %a{ href: "/"}
    = my_image_tag "logo.png" , :id => 'logo'
```

but this dosen't

```
%nav
  = my_link "", "/"
    = my_image_tag "logo.png" , :id => 'logo'
```

any ideas?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `do` to indicate a Ruby block:

```
%nav
  = my_link "", "/" do
    = my_image_tag "logo.png" , :id => 'logo'
```